# Issue executing a query

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have created two tables in the Android SQLite using the following queries:

```
public static final String TABLE_SEMESTER_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + SemesterTable.TABLE_NAME + " (" + SemesterTable.ID_PK
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + SemesterTable.TITLE
        + " TEXT," + SemesterTable.START_DATE + " TEXT, "
        + SemesterTable.END_DATE + " TEXT) ";


public static final String TABLE_COURSE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + CourseTable.TABLE_NAME + " (" + CourseTable.ID_PK
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + CourseTable.COURSE_CODE
        + " TEXT, " + CourseTable.COURSE_NAME + " TEXT, "
        + CourseTable.LOCATION + " TEXT, " + CourseTable.SEMESTER_ID_FK
        + " INTEGER, " + "FOREIGN KEY (" + CourseTable.SEMESTER_ID_FK
        + ") REFERENCES " + SemesterTable.TABLE_NAME + " ("
        + SemesterTable.ID_PK + "));";
```

Then i inserted some data in the Parent table and in the child table. The problem is that when i execute the query:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + CourseTable.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
            + CourseTable.SEMESTER_ID_FK + " = 1;";
    database.rawQuery(query, null);;
```

It does not execute. Can you please help me to get rid of this error?
I have also tried.

```
database.query(CourseTable.TABLE_NAME, CourseTable.allColumns,
    CourseTable.SEMESTER_ID_FK + " = ? ",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(semesterID) }, null, null, null);
```

**But it is also not working !**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is char **`;`** that is not allowed. So correct your query like this:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + CourseTable.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
            + CourseTable.SEMESTER_ID_FK + " = ?";
database.rawQuery(query, new String[] {String.valueOf(1)});
```

Now it will works. I recommend to you use **`?`** that is called as **`placeholder`** and will be replaced with value from **`String-array`** as second parameter of `rawQuery()` method.

Also remove last **`;`** char from your **`TABLE_COURSE_CREATE`** `String`.

**Note:** Always use it and with this approach you will avoid any problems.

Comment: Is that a specific restriction of Android?  Because SQLite has no problem at all with `;` at the end of a query. I agree on the parameter binding, though.

Comment: if you work with db directly for example in SQLite Expert or Oracle SQLData Developer and etc. **`;`** char is OK but if you connect to db from application layer(Java,...) **`;`** is not allowed(this is also when you working on some WebApplication is classic Java SE, this char is also not allowed there.)

Comment: OK, so it’s a Java restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Two tips to increase your chances of getting a helpful answer (or better yet, figuring out the problem by yourself):

1. What is the actual error message?  SQLite usually tells you exactly why it's not able to run your query.
2. Instead of the (almost illegible) code you gave here, could you [log](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html) the resulting SQL, and post that here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing an equal sign?  Your first query is evaluating to something like:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD1
```

Change this:

```
"SELECT * FROM " + CourseTable.TABLE_NAME + 
" WHERE " + CourseTable.SEMESTER_ID_FK + "1;"
```

To:

```
"SELECT * FROM " + CourseTable.TABLE_NAME + 
" WHERE " + CourseTable.SEMESTER_ID_FK + "=1;"
```

Comment: Thanks @sgeddes i forgot to put = sign while posting here. '"SELECT * FROM " + CourseTable.TABLE_NAME + 
" WHERE " + CourseTable.SEMESTER_ID_FK + "=1;"' also not works.

Comment: @user1773155 -- what does your query evaluate to when you print it out?  Can you run it directly against the DB?  Assuming that works, then your issue might be elsewhere.

Comment: i am executing it in the android project. When the app reach at the point of execution of this query it stops.